# How to get multiple text colors for a single NSTextField in Swift?

Tags: swift

```
textfield.stringValue = "This part red - here some blue"
```

All that inside one textfield in two different colors.

Could I put HTML code inside the textfield? Because I also want to provide a url link inside a textfield, so that would solve two problems.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the NSMutableAttributedString class to achieve this.

**Example:**

```
 attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 18.0)!])
 attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:0,length:2))
```

This example creates an NSMutableAttributedString and then adds an attribute that sets the string to have a red font color for the characters at location 0 to 2.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are methods for initializing an attributed string from HTML in the `NSAttributedString` App Kit Additions or UIKit Additions, as the case may be.   (You didn't say whether you're doing Mac or iOS.) Once you have an `NSAttributedString`, assign it to the `attributedStringValue` property of the field.